# Can I configure my google account to always accept requests from my app?

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

In my we app, I'd like to provide my users Google Spreadsheets where they can fill information and my app can parse it from there. **I want to be the owner of the spreadsheet**, and just configure it as editable for anyone that has the link (i.e. my users).

I don't need access to users Google Drive info (they can even do not have one!), I just need access to my team's Google Drive info and then I provide them the right link.

Is it possible to make this account (my team's) always accept requests from my app? (In order not to refresh the access token every hour)

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few points,

1. Refreshing the access token should be seamless of you have "offline" access, and the client library should do it automatically.
2. If you really want unmanned access, you can use a service account that is an email address associated with the API console. https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount

Comment: I've just gone through the protocol specs. It's not that hard!